# CIContext + createCGImage + UIImage Crash

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage, cgcontext, ciimage

### What I am Doing:

I am taking **CMSampleBuffer** from **didOutputSampleBuffer** in **AVFoundation** and running few filters through and outputting them in to an **UIImage** every time the delegate spit out a buffer.

### What's Working:

All the filters work fine.  It gives me the output I want.  Everything runs fine on a new phone (iPhone 6/6s/7); however, **it freezes after few seconds** on iPhone 5s.

### Filters & UIImage Output:

```
let inputImage = self.bufferImage!

let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPixellate")
let beginImage = inputImage
filter!.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

let filter3 = CIFilter(name: "CIColorMonochrome")
filter3!.setValue(filter!.outputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
filter3!.setValue(CIColor(red: 1, green:0, blue: 0), forKey: kCIInputColorKey)
filter3!.setValue(200.0, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)

let filter2 = CIFilter(name: "CIMultiplyBlendMode")
filter2!.setValue(filter3!.outputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
filter2!.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputBackgroundImageKey)
let output2 = filter2!.outputImage

let cgimg = self.context.createCGImage(output2!, fromRect: output2!.extent)
let newImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgimg!)
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
     self.imageView?.image = newImage
}
self.context.clearCaches()
```

I create CIContext as:

```
let context = CIContext(options: nil)
```

I also tried forcing CIContext to render on hardware, and vise versa.

I feel like, something is running out of memory/space/leak/ect, although, the when it freezes, there is no error in Xcode, just the app at frozen state. I added **self.context.clearCaches()** at the end, if didn't really change anything to the original issue.

**THIS ONLY HAPPENS ON SLOWER DEVICES** - 5S in this case, runs smoothly without any issues on 6/6s/7.

My full **didOutputSampleBuffer** for reference:

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    connection.videoOrientation = .Portrait
    let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: CVOptionFlags(0)))

    let baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer!)

    let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer!)

    let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer!)
    let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer!)

    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

    let bitmap = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Little.rawValue|CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst.rawValue)
    let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8,
                                        bytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmap.rawValue)

    let quartzImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context!)

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer!,CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: CVOptionFlags(0)))

    self.bufferImage = CIImage(CGImage: quartzImage!)

            let inputImage = self.bufferImage!

            let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPixellate")
            let beginImage = inputImage
            filter!.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

            let filter3 = CIFilter(name: "CIColorMonochrome")
            filter3!.setValue(filter!.outputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            filter3!.setValue(CIColor(red: 1, green:0, blue: 0), forKey: kCIInputColorKey)
            filter3!.setValue(200.0, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)

            let filter2 = CIFilter(name: "CIMultiplyBlendMode")
            filter2!.setValue(filter3!.outputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            filter2!.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputBackgroundImageKey)
            let output2 = filter2!.outputImage

            let cgimg = self.context.createCGImage(output2!, fromRect: output2!.extent)
            let newImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgimg!)

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.imageView?.image = newImage
            }
            self.context.clearCaches()
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

I was able to fix the freezing by changing the method of getting the pixel buffer to become CIImage:

```
let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)!
self.bufferImage = CIImage(CVPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
```

Took out most of the code in the begining of didOutputSampleBuffer.

However, now **CPU useage is significantly high!**  Xcode showing 'Engergy Impact' as high!

Answer (score 1):

You are saying:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
     self.imageView?.image = newImage
}
```

You have no reason whatever to wait around for the result of this call. Use `dispatch_async` instead.

(Even better would be: find out whether you are on the main thread. If so, don't use `dispatch` anything at all.)

Comment: I apologize.  I was trying sync from async.  I edited the OP back to async.  I have to goto main thread, didOutputSampleBuffer is happening in a different thread.

Comment: when I don't use dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()), self.imageView?.image doesn't get displayed at all.

Comment: The only reason I can think of why that would be true would be if `self.imageView` is `nil`. Try logging and see.

Comment: Also I have to say I find your whole strategy a little disturbing. You are trying to draw to the interface as fast as buffers come in. That seems a little nutty.

Comment: if I take out the going in to the main thread, then self.imageView does get nil.  How else would you recommend this? I have to update the ImageView with what ever the buffer shows.

Comment: And all above runs smoothly on iPhone 6s.  When I run on 5s, that's when it freezes after few seconds of working.

Comment: The iPhone 5s is (1) slower and (2) not multithreaded. Maybe you should try dropping some frames...?

Comment: 5s is not multithreaded? In what sense? For my requirements, it still runs Metal and is 64bit.

Comment: It's dual core not quad core. Makes a big difference when you're doing what you're doing. You should use Instruments to get a hold of what's going on here.